# Multiply relationships ef core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using entity core 3. I have 2 classes `User` and `Ticket`. `User` may have many `Ticket`'s to me and many `Ticket`'s from me. `Ticket` should have `User`-sender and `User`-receiver. I did so:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; 
    public ICollection<Ticket> TicketsToMe { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Ticket> TicketsFromMe { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int UserToId { get; set; }
    public int UserFromId { get; set; }
    public User UserTo { get; set; }
    public User UserFrom { get; set; }
}
```

And I got the error: *Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Ticket.UserTo' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.*

Do you have any ideas?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these

1 - Metadata. you can use `InverseProperty` to define the relationships.

> if you use the metadata you should set `UserToId` and `UserFromId` to `Nullable`

```cs
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("UserTo")]
    public ICollection<Ticket> TicketsToMe { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("UserFrom")]
    public ICollection<Ticket> TicketsFromMe { get; set; }
}
```

2 - FluentApi

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(a => a.TicketsFromMe)
        .WithOne(a => a.UserFrom)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.UserFromId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); 
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(a => a.TicketsToMe)
        .WithOne(a => a.UserTo)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.UserToId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); 
}
```

Comment: I tried it. I'm using Update-Database and get error: _Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Tickets_Users_UserToId' on table 'Tickets' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints._

Comment: But I don't want use FluentApi. I use [InverseProperty] and for Foreign Key I use nullable int, and it's working) Thanks!